# Images not loading in emails with CDN Hosts url rails

Tags: ruby, cdn

I recently moved all my app assets to CDN and everything is working fine. All images are loading in views. But my problem is my images are not loading in emails which I am sending from my application. I have specified `my CDN Path` in `production.rb` file also  but still not working. When I inspect that image in email, I didn't even getting `src` for that image.

I am loading my images using `image_tag`.

Can anyone please help me on this:

**Production.rb:**

```
  config.action_controller.asset_host = AssetsCdn.new
  config.action_mailer.asset_host = AssetsCdn.new


 config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'localhost', :protocol => 'http' } 
config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true   config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = false   config.action_mailer.default :charset => "utf-8"  
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp #:mailhopper
```

**AssetsCdn Class:**

```
require 'zlib'
class AssetsCdn
  CSS_CDN   = "cdn-css"
  CSS_CDN_0 = "cdn-css0"
  CSS_CDN_1 = "cdn-css1"
  CSS_CDN_2 = "cdn-css2"

  JS_CDN    = "cdn-js"  
  JS_CDN_0  = "cdn-js0"
  JS_CDN_1  = "cdn-js1"
  JS_CDN_2  = "cdn-js2"  

  ASSETS_CDN   = "cdn-assets"
  ASSETS_CDN_0 = "cdn-assets0"
  ASSETS_CDN_1 = "cdn-assets1"
  ASSETS_CDN_2 = "cdn-assets2"
  ALL = [CSS_CDN_0, CSS_CDN_1, CSS_CDN_2, JS_CDN_0, JS_CDN_1, JS_CDN_2, ASSETS_CDN_0, ASSETS_CDN_1, ASSETS_CDN_2]

  def call(source, request = nil)
    cdn_index = Zlib.crc32(source) % 3
    if source.ends_with?('.css')
      url("#{CSS_CDN}#{cdn_index}", request)
    elsif source.ends_with?('.js')
      url("#{JS_CDN}#{cdn_index}", request)
    else  
      url("#{ASSETS_CDN}#{cdn_index}", request)
    end
  end

  def url(cdn_subdomain, request = nil)
      return "//#{cdn_subdomain}-#{localhost}:3000"
  end
end
```

TIA.

Comment: @spickermann I am using one class to generate dynamic urls for my js, css and image files. So in production.rb I am creating object  for that class. In views and all is working fine. but in emails it is not serving. I am not getting any link to that image in email. empty image tag is showing

Comment: @spickermann: `<img alt="Logo" height="100%" src="" width="100%" class="CToWUd">` like that I am getting image in email

Comment: @spickermann I am calling that class in prodcution.rb  like suppose that class name is AssetsCDN, I am using this: `config.action_mailer.asset_host = AssetsCDN.new`. In that we are generating URLS with paths of images

Comment: @spickermann I added code please help me out.

Comment: @spickermann Hey Man!, You made my day Thank you so much It worked like a charm. Please post it as answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`action_mailer.assets_host` doesn't accept protocol relative URLs. Instead URLs have to start with with a protocol like `http://` or `https://`.

This makes kind of sense, because usually emails aren't opened in a browser and email clients are not able to inherit the protocol from a patent html document like browsers do.